# Does Judgement add Black Cleaver stacks?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing a lot of Garen lately, and what I tend to buy first is a [Black Cleaver](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Cleaver), I noticed when I build it, [Garen's Judgement](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Garen/Ability_Details#Judgement) does a lot of damage. Now I know Judgement can proc critical hits, but can it also proc the armor debuffs from Black Cleaver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They changed the Black Cleaver so it WILL actually trigger with garen's judgement.
It used to be just an on hit effect (with auto attacks).
The simple truth can be found here: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Cleaver

Under tab Strategy it says:

> The armor-shred passive triggers not only auto-attacks but on any
>   effect which deals physical damage, such as  Urgot's  Acid Hunter, 
>   Garen's  Judgment, and  Pantheon's  Heartseeker Strike.

Comment: Also has been mentioned by mods on the official LoL forums.  It's in the thread where they talked about Black Cleaver remake, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @boiledham Yeah, but i found some counter arguments on the forums aswell, that is why i asked. But now I know why i've been shredding people with Judgement :).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does; dealing any physical damage to an enemy champion procs the passive.  This is actually one of the easiest ways to get up Black Cleaver stacks on an opponent.

[Reference](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Cleaver)